# Create Java stub from Hibernate ORM file

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, orm, jaxb

Is there any jar which which will help me to create Java files from an existing hibernate orm-xml file?
Like we have an avro utility to convert (avsc) to .java files.
We have orm files and want to move toward Entity classes with annotations rather than using the orm files.

I tried converting xml- xsd and then using jaxb over it but failed.

Answer (score 0):

JPA has no generator, there is no way of doing this.

It is never a good idea to mix data transfer objects (DTOs) together.

Your SOAP XML generated classes should only be used for the external API (SOAP DTOs).

Your application model should manage the persistence separately (JPA DTOs).

Doing it this way allows you to later change the API and the application model independently of each other.

It also allows you to easily add another API, e.g. REST and use REST DTOs for that (typically JSON).